# What is the mechanism of returning a structure from a function in C

Tags: c, structure

Could some one please explain, how the structure variable return from a function is implemented. basically when a single variable is returned from a function, the value will be put in a register and return. but in case of structure return, how this will work. I assume that structure will be copied to some global location and return the pointer. This will be managed by compiler. Is my understanding correct ?

This is what my sample program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ss
{
  char name[10];
  int val;
} HELLO;


HELLO *ptr=NULL;

HELLO myfun()
{
   HELLO hel = {"Salil", 20};
   ptr = &hel;
   return hel;
}
main()
{

  HELLO hel1;
  hel1 = myfun();
  if ( ptr ) printf("The val = %s \n", ptr->name);
}
```

Here in `myfun`, how will the `hel` variable returned? Where will the variable be kept while returning?

Comment: Orr is just set to a variable on the stacks lap this question depends on the calling convention you are using. NEVER MAKE POINTERS TO A VARIABLE ON THE STACK AND HAVE THE CALLER USE IT. IT WILL FAIL AND BE HARD TO DETECT WHY

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the compiler and the ABI of the target.  Some that I have seen:

- multiple registers: small structs can be returned in several registers in some ABIs
- global buffer: a buffer can be allocated somewhere that the caller and callee both know about.
- on stack, caller's frame: the caller can allocate extra space on the stack and pass the address of that space as an hidden extra argument to the function.
- on stack replacing args: In ABIs where the callee pops args from the stack, it may replace them with the return value.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any way we can see how the mechanism works using objdump or some thing.

Comment: If you disassemble the function, or just compile with -S, then you can read the assembly and see what the compiler is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a structure only a pointer to it, provided we are talking about `C`. Assuming you allocated the space for your `struct` via `malloc`/`calloc` it is the pointer which would be returned. It is difficult to tell whether it would be returned in a register or on the stack, that depends on the optimisation level.

Comment: -1: not true, C has allowed returning structures since at least the original C89 ANSI standard, and many implementations before that.